# Minimum of n independent, but not identically distributed inverse Gaussians

Tags: probability, distributions, extreme-value, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I would like to find the probability distribution of the minimum of of n independent, but not identically distributed, i.e. differently parametrized inverse Gaussians. I would prefer an analytical solution. Also, would it make it simpler if I was only interested in the first few moments?

EDIT: the inverse Gaussians are parametrized as

[image]

What varies between them is T.

Particularly, I am interested in the first moment of the minimum distribution, and in the variance of

[image]

Where Z is the minimum distribution mentioned above. For starters at least.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am talking about this distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution
What exactly do you mean by negative? The inverse Gaussian is not Gaussian, except in the limit of one of its parameters going to infinity. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Sorry; I overlooked the "inverse" part of the question for some reason!  I will delete my comment lest it confuse some readers.  Regardless, there won't be an analytical solution: this is apparent from the form of the CDF of the minimum. Obtaining moments or reasonable approximations might be feasible, but if there are any specifics you could offer about the "different parameterizations" describing how the parameters vary, that might help.

Comment: This is very broad, and for an answer you should probably specify the way in which the marginal distributions differ. Otherwise an answer requires a book. A paper you could look at is:  [Maxima of independent, non-identically
distributed Gaussian vectors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0947.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have added some details to the question.

Comment: Is the first sentence missing "the minimum of" as in "find the probability distribution of [the minimum of] $n$ independent..."?

Comment: yes, I'll correct that